# Adjust MkMapView Annotation

Tags: ios, image, annotations, mkmapview

I'm adding annotations to an MkMapView and am using a custom image to do so. My custom image is box shaped with a little triangular arrow that's supposed to be right on the place that's being annotated. It seems like MapView by default annotates using the geometric center of the image. What's the best way to design around this problem? Manually moving the icon? Creating the icon in a specific way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the Apple docs for `MKAnnotationView`'s [`centerOffset`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKAnnotationView/centerOffset) property:

> By default, the center point of an annotation view is placed at the coordinate point of the associated annotation. You can use this property to reposition the annotation view as needed. This x and y offset values are measured in pixels. Positive offset values move the annotation view down and to the right, while negative values move it up and to the left.